# How to make a scope with a raw SQL query in Laravel 7?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-backpack

## Problem

I am trying to make a **scope** in my **model** with this **SQL query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM ro_container_events
WHERE (container_id, location_timestamp, id)
IN (
    SELECT distinct container_id, MAX(location_timestamp) AS lts, MAX(id) AS rce_id
    FROM ro_container_events
    GROUP BY container_id
)
```

The model name is **ContainerEvent** and the name of the table in my database is **ro_container_events**.

Also, I know that the SQL query is valid because I ran it in my MySQL administration tool (HeidiSQL), and it returns the good rows.

## What I've tried

My scope (in my **ContainerEvent** model) currently looks like this:

```
public function scopeLatestEventForContainers($query)
    {
       return $query->select(DB::raw('
            SELECT *
            FROM ro_container_events
            WHERE (container_id, location_timestamp, id)
            IN (
                SELECT distinct container_id, MAX(location_timestamp) AS lts, MAX(id) AS rce_id
                FROM ro_container_events
                GROUP BY container_id
            )'
       )
       );
    }
```

But it doesn't return any rows?

## My research

I've been searching about this topic for a while but can't seem to find what is wrong with my scope...

The Laravel documentation says that we can use :

```
DB::raw('...')
```

In order to make a specific SQL query.

And I've seen on some other threads that I should be able to make a scope with the following :

```
return $query->select(DB::raw('...');
```

Comment: Have you tried print_r() where you put inside print_r what the function returns?

Answer (score 0):

try Eloquent:

```
//as your where in select this must return just one row with 3 field
$in =  ContainerEvent::distinct('container_id', 'location_timestamp', 'id')->where(fn($q) => {
   'id' => ContainerEvent::max('id')
   'location_timestamp' => ContainerEvent::max('location_timestamp')
])->get();
```

but it may be wrong because there is ambitious in db structure.

Comment: can you give me result of ContainerEvent::get(container_id, max(location_timestamp), max(id))
       ->distinct(); ?

Comment: It gives no result. Correct me if I'm wrong but you can't give 3 parameters to get()...?

Comment: try on my project this situation. this not best, but surely do what you need. answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

I just try your SQL syntax using Laravel query builder, and the result using method `toSql()` returns the exact thing that you need.

```
SELECT * FROM ro_container_events WHERE (container_id, location_timestamp, id) IN (
    SELECT distinct container_id, MAX(location_timestamp) AS lts, MAX(id) AS rce_id
    FROM ro_container_events
    GROUP BY container_id
)
```

Try this function:

```
public function scopeLatestEventForContainers($query)
{
    return $query->whereIn(\DB::raw('(container_id, location_timestamp, id)'), function ($q) {
        $q->distinct()->select(\DB::raw('
            container_id,
            MAX(location_timestamp) AS lts,
            MAX(id) AS rce_id FROM `ro_container_events`
        '))->groupBy('container_id');
    });
}
```

Hope that's help :)

Best,
vreedom18